# Function and Limit problem

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ be a differentiable function which satisfies the functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)e^y+f(y)e^x+2xye^xe^y\:\forall\: x,y \in R$ and $f'(x)=0$, number of solution(s) of equation $f(x)=0$ is

I tried using **derivative by first principle** but can't solve the limits

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: I' m still learning to use the site; don't down vote me. I didn't thought my progress was worth mentioning that's all

Comment: Did you really mean to write $f'(x)=0$? Is that supposed to be true for all $x,$ or only for some particular $x$?

Comment: I don't get the $ f'(x) = 0 $ part... for what interval of x is this true ?

Comment: I guess $f'(x)=0$ is valid for any real value of x

Comment: But still i have my posted my attempt as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $x=y=0$; from there we get $f(0)=0$.

Then we use *derivative by first principles* by putting $y=h$
$$f'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{[f(x)e^h+f(h)e^x+2xhe^xe^h]-f(x)}{h}=f(x)+2xe^x$$
By inspection we have $f(x)=x^2e^x$
and the number of solutions of $x^2e^x=0$ is $1\text{ i.e. when }x=0.$